# Can't add default consent to Google Tag Manager

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I'm trying to add default consent to Google Tag Manager, but when I do it I get a `TypeError: $window.ga is not a function` error on the console. Does anyone know what the issue could be?

This is now I'm implementing it

```
<!-- Google Tag Manager Default Consent -->
<script>
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}

    gtag('consent', 'default', {
        'ad_storage': 'denied',
        'analytics_storage': 'denied'
    });
</script>

<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
            new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
                    j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
                    'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
            })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-MY_TAG');</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
```

this are the settings for the Google Analytics Tag
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You make a few mistakes right away.

1. You don't need to set consent in gtag directly if you use GTM.
2. You failed to indicate whether you're trying to work with GA UA or GA4. On one hand, you're trying to set consent with gtag, which implies GA4; on the other hand, you're trying to set consent for GA UA. And your error is talking about the ga() function that comes from the analytics.js, which is the UA library.
3. Make a GA4 tag, set consent in it, get rid of what you're doing with gtag. Proceed from there.

You don't want to implement new features for UA. It's being deprecated.

Comment: If you're implementing consent manually (ie. without the help of a Consent Management Platform and their associated tags in GTM), you do need to call gtag directly - how else is GTM going to know what consent has been given? Here is a video from the official Google Analytics channel showing code that does just this: https://youtu.be/MqAEbshMv84?si=0FSzBBnjDbwQgCHY&t=203

Comment: No, no you most definitely don't need to do that. GTM will know in any way you tell it. Usually either via the DL or a cookie. Custom solutions are most perfectly fine. Even having both gtag and GTM loaded as separate scripts is not a good practice. I have no idea why they're going through that scenario in the video, but that's definitely multiple ways to implementing consent and what they're featuring there is a bit obscure.

Comment: In the supplied code (and the code in the video), gtag is not 'loaded', it's just a locally defined function which creates a dataLayer to be consumed by GTM. Perhaps there are other ways to supply the consent to GTM, but you haven't outlined them in your answer and your suggestion is to remove the only way it is occurring at present. We're both talking about Google Consent Mode v2 right?

Comment: If you want to use the consent mode, [here](https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/consent-mode-v2-google-tags/) Simo made a very good article. I guess it's counter-intuitive, but google's documentation /guides are surprisingly inept. I have to add that using the consent mode is not the best practice. Industry experts mostly chose to control consent manually through blockers and CJS variables rather than a blackbox consent mode. This is because different jurisdictions have different laws on consent and even in the same jurisdiction, the interpretation varies between companies.

Comment: In the end, when you have a lot of input from your legal team of what's allowed when and what's not, you need to write so much customization that the benefit of the built-in consent mode becomes a burden and you would much rather just implement all of it.

Comment: It's a great article. I happened to read that today actually. I'm receptive to your suggestion of implementing custom consent as I spent all of today moving my tags away from GTM after realising that adblockers block the GTM script. Can't have your consent management platform tied up with a tag manager that's blocked for a fair percentage of your users... 

Comment: Well we raised it with different legal teams multiple times and they say it's not our responsibility. If a user chooses to block part of the site's functionality, we can't be liable for that functionality not working. So actually, we can. A lot of fortune 500 corps do exactly that - make consent dependable on TMSes knowing that the TMSes are blocked by adblockers.